# Schedule the creation a partitioned table overwriting an existing table in BigQuery GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

Yesterday I scheduled daily the overwriting of a table. The new table will be partitioned as well as the overwritten one... It did not run at the corresponding time, nor gave an error... It just did not started.

My feeling is that it has to be with the partitioning option. To mention that the casting of the field *date_formatted* that will be used as partition field works fine.

As far as I know, when scheduling a query you can't use the `create or replace table T partitioned by column C as select`...

You starts from the `select...` clause, as shows in the image, and I don't know if the problem comes from here.

[image]

PS: I had no troubles scheduling the appending to a partitioned by day table with this same procedure.

Answer (score 0):

the destination table is in the same dataset.
if the very same query is scheduled to deliver the results in a table with the same name, but in a different dataset (located in the same project), it works.

by the way, the input table and the output table never were the same.